чтение и запись текстбоксов в цикле
проблема в том, что текстбоксы лежат в панели panel1, которая лежит в панели panelshed
большая панель
string str;
std::ofstream out("schedule"+ID+".txt");
if (out.is_open())
{
    for (int i = 1; i<15; i++)
    {
        str = SystemToStl(this->panelshed->Controls["textBox" + i.ToString()]->Text);
        out << str << std::endl;
    }
}
out.close();


System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

маленькая панель
str = SystemToStl(this->panel1->Controls["textBox" + i.ToString()]->Text);


System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

другой вариант
str = SystemToStl(this->Controls["textBox" + i.ToString()]->Text);


System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

еще
str = SystemToStl(this->panelshed->panel1->Controls["textBox" + i.ToString()]->Text);
                                     ^
Ошибка (активно)    E0135   класс "System::Windows::Forms::Panel" не содержит члена "panel1"

обновление. чтение в таком виде работает
std::string line;
std::ifstream in("schedule" + ID + ".txt");
if (in.is_open())
{
    int i = 1;
    while (std::getline(in, line))
    {
        String^ line2 = gcnew String(line.c_str());
        this->panel1->Controls["textbox" + i.ToString()]->Text = line2;            ///////////работает
        i++;
    }
}
in.close();panel1


такой вариант сработал, но он разбирает текстбоксы рандомно.
проблема была в не приложенном куске кода.
for each(Control^ c in panel1->Controls)
{
    if (isinst< TextBox^ >(c))
    {
        str = SystemToStl(c->Text);
        out << str << std::endl;
    }
}

